# Efficient way to assign a value to a String variable in a loop

Tags: java, string

I am assigning a value to a String variable (`name`) in a while loop. I understand that the String data type is immutable and if I assign 1000 different values to the same String variable it will create a 1000 references in the String Constant pool. However, I am not able to think of any other efficient way of doing this... please advice...

```
while ((name = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    //Add each character in the name to the list
    for (char c : name.toCharArray()) {
        if (c != ' ') {  
            list.add(Character.toLowerCase(c));                     
        }
    }               
    namesCount++;         
}
```

Comment: What is `list`  ? And I don't see any Strings here. All are characters

Comment: List<Character> list = new ArrayList<Character>();

Comment: `Eficient way to assign a value to string variable in a loop` Where is your String ?

Comment: are you talking abt `name = reader.readLine()` line ?

Comment: Suresh Atta, Rehman: Yes, the name is the String variable that I am referring to.

Comment: `name = reader.readLine()`   in a while loop. So in the next iteration earlier object (referred by `name`) will be eligible for garbage collection.  So I dont think it will be an issue

Comment: @Rehman That's it, go-ahead and answer it.

Comment: Rehman and Suresh Atta: Perfect! That is what I thought! However, its always nice to know from experts about the good practices. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should be good with `name = reader.readLine()` and that's a good practice. However since you asked about string pool in java, here is a nice explanation on when to use `direct string assignment vs new String(...)` and how it affects your heap - http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/06/19/the-string-constant-pool/